# Error while inflating in fragment but works in an Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to inflate a class in my fragment which shows table of n*n. It works when i set it in an activity but give error in an fragment. Code has been provided below.

Activity:

```java
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new TableMainLayout(this));
    }
}
```

Fragment

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return inflater.inflate(new TableMainLayout(context), container, false);
    }
```

It gives me this error

> "Cannot resolve method 'inflate(com.example.wasalahore.TableMainLayout, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean)"** on line return inflater.inflate(new TableMainLayout(context), container, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because whenever your using the following code in Activity:

```
setContentView(new TableMainLayout(this));
```

the [`setContentView(android.view.View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View)) will be used.

But there is no equivalent method of `Inflater.inflate()` with view as one of the parameters. The closest one that you can use is only [`inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#inflate(int,%2520android.view.ViewGroup,%2520boolean))

You can't use the following:

```
return inflater.inflate(new TableMainLayout(context), container, false);
```

because the method `Inflater.inflate(View view, ViewGroup root, boolean attachToRoot);` is not exit.

You need to use an XML layout resource for the `Inflater.inflate` method instead. Something like this:

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
```

Comment: Will this work     <com.example.wasalahore.TableMainLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

Comment: That should be work whenever you add it inside the layout.